# Injecting $http fails in jasmine testing with typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, typescript, inject

we are developing a programm test-driven in Typescript.
This is our test with jasmine:

```
import IDifferentialPilotService = DifferentialPilot.IDifferentialPilotService;
import Ev3DifferentialPilotService = DifferentialPilot.Ev3DifferentialPilotService;
import IHttpService = ng.IHttpService;

describe("restClientService integration test: ", function () {

    // sut
    var ev3DifferentialPilotService: IDifferentialPilotService;

    //doc
    var http: IHttpService;

    beforeAll(function () {
        angular.mock.inject(function ($http: IHttpService) {
            this.http = $http;
        });
        ev3DifferentialPilotService = new Ev3DifferentialPilotService(http);
    });

    it("robot should run 5 m", function () {
expect(ev3DifferentialPilotService.runDistance(5)).toBe("success");

    });

});
```

the class `Ev3DifferentialPilotService`  which is tested looks like that:

```
namespace DifferentialPilot {
    "use strict";

    import IHttpService = ng.IHttpService;

    export class Ev3DifferentialPilotService implements IDifferentialPilotService {
        private http: IHttpService;

        static $inject = ['$http'];
        constructor($http: IHttpService) {
            this.http = $http;
        }

        public runDistance(runDistance: number): string {
            this.http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "10.0.0.44:8080/differentpilot/run/5"
            }).then(function successCallback(response: any) {
                return "success";
            }, function errorCallback(response: any) {
                return "error";
            });

            return undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Like you can see, we want to inject in our test the `$http`-service, so that `Ev3DifferentialPilotService` can retrieve the Http-service as parameter and use it in its `runDistance`-method.
When we log the `this.$http`-Object in `Ev3DifferentialPilotService` , then we get `undefined`, what means that the injection fails. According to that the test also fails.

Im registrating `Ev3DifferentialPilotService` as service in `App.js`:

```
var app = angular.module("AngularDifferentialPilotModule", []);
app.service("ev3DifferentialPilotService", DifferentialPilot.Ev3DifferentialPilotService);
```

And we using all that stuff in our karam.conf.js:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Dec 17 2015 14:02:38 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '',


        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            "bower_components/angular/angular.js",
            "bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js",
            "src/Ev3DifferentialPilotService.js",
            "spec/*.spec.js",
            "src/app.js"
        ],

        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [],


        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {},


        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['progress'],


        // web server port
        port: 9876,


        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,


        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: false,


        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ['Firefox'],


        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: false,

        // Concurrency level
        // how many browser should be started simultanous
        concurrency: Infinity
    })
}
```

Furthermore we are using a tsconfig which looks like that:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  }
```

So where is the error? Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't inject in `beforeAll` (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10238)

A feature has been opened (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/14093) but not yet merged.